# In WPF , Group ListBox or ListView based on property of Custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, group-by, listboxitem

```
// class-1
public class Owner
{
public string Name { get; set; }
}

//class 2
public class Product
{
public string Name { get; set; }
}

//class 3
public class Order
{ 
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Owner Owner { get; set; }
  public Product Product{ get; set; }
}
```

In my Code I have list of Order class objects

```
List<Order> orders = getList();
```

In my XAML I have a listbox.  I want group that list based on the name property from 'Order'class  by displaying owner name and Product name correspondingly.

I want my list should display as following

```
Order_One_name
    Owner_One_Name
    Product_One_Name
Order_Two_name
    Owner_Two_Name
    Product_Two_Name
Order_Three_name
    Owner_Three_Name
    Product_Three_Name
           .
           .
           .
           .
```

I tried something like below , but it only display order names. Thanks in advance.

```
  PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new 
         PropertyGroupDescription("Name");
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);

             .
             .
```

Comment: Learn about DataTemplating. Using a DataTemplate for your `Order` objects in the list (with respect to ListBoxes/ItemsControls, such DataTemplates are also often called item templates), you can ceate a custom visual representation of the order items in the listbox (like showing the owner and product information belonging to the order) (See here for a brief overview of DataTemplates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating#data-templates)

Comment: "Only display order names"? Well, you group by the Name property so what do you expect? Please clarify your issue.

Comment: I want display List-item in customized ,@elgonzo concept of Data Templates concept worked for me.I didn't know it earlier . Thanks